# Trying to update from Windows Insider Slow Ring, get this error: Windows 10 Insider Preview 16251.0 (rs3_release) - Error 0xc1900201

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-preview, windows-insider

As the description says, I'm trying to update to Windows 10 Insider Preview 16251.0, but I get an error 0xc1900201. I've rebooted the computer multiple times, with no luck. The update installs to about 85% or so, and a Windows Update window opens, saying "We Couldn't Update The System Reserved Partition".
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you pause the Insider Preview ring and wait until 1709 is released and/or the next slow ring ISO is released but in either case mount the ISO and install the update that way.

Comment: have you tried the final 16299.15? does it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION & IT WORKED FINE!** 
1. Install Minitool partition free version.
2. FInd your system reserved partition. It was a 100MB partition and ( In the status column it says "Active & System"
3. Right click on the partition and select extend.
 
(I extended 100MB more) Then just follow the instructions(It says restart to complete) & it's DONE! –

Comment: @keenan  this is what I already told you. your system reserved was too small. it is 500MB for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the error code `0xc1900201` on the [Microsoft upgrade help documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors), shows that the Hardware is incompatible with the new Windows 10 Build:

```
0xC1900201 - The system did not pass the minimum requirements to install the update.
```

So without any details we can't answer this. It is known that Intel Atom Z2xxx cpus are no longer compatible with recent Windows 10 builds and have to stay at Windows 10 v1607.

`"We Couldn't Update The System Reserved Partition"` may indicate a problem, that the hidden system partition is running out of space. Use a 3rd party tool to increase the size of the partition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can you recommend any easy and secure apps to increase the partition?

Comment: try several tools. also check how much space is used. also look in the [setuperr.log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors#log-files) for more details.

Comment: any update on your issue?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the delay. I've decided to just wait until the update reaches the Stable channel, and hopefully it'll work. Also, I don't have the Intel Atom Z2xxx processor. I have a Toshiba C75D-B with an AMD A6-6310 processor. Thanks

Comment: please share the setup logs (setuperr.log and setupact.log) from $Windows.~BT\Sources\Panther