# Feature update to Windows 10, version 1709 - Error 0xc1900201

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1709

How to fix this? :( I saw there's something that reserving more space to reserved partition will help the problem. If it is correct please guide me through.
System specs
i5-5200u
4GB DDR3 
Thanks!

Comment: Please see this post first: https://superuser.com/questions/1240321/trying-to-update-from-windows-insider-slow-ring-get-this-error-windows-10-insi

Comment: Did version 1709 attempt to install automatically, or did you initiate the update yourself?

Comment: Update your question to include you precise system specifications.

Comment: @music2myear Yeah I saw that post but I didn't get any help from it that's why I post this :(

Comment: @Ramhound oh I forgot it

Answer (score 2):

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION & IT WORKED FINE!** 
1. Install Minitool partition free version
 2. FInd your system reserved partition. It was a 100MB partition and ( In the status column it says "Active & System"
 3. Right click on the partition and select extend. 
(I extended 100MB more) Then just follow the instructions(It says restart to complete) & it's DONE! –